# PropertyChangedCallback encapsulation

Tags: c#, wpf, callback, encapsulation

This has been bugging me for a while, so I asked a coworker if he could make any sense of it, and now I'm here ;)

How come you can access private members of the holding class in the PropertyChangedCallback of a dependency property?
Let me explain further what i mean through this example:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ZeControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ZeControl : UserControl
    {
        public ZeControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private bool m_Trololo; //Please note that this field is PRIVATE!

        #region Text
        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ZeControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(
                new PropertyChangedCallback((dpo, dpce) =>
                    {
                        ((ZeControl)dpo).m_Trololo = true; //How the hell?
                        //this.m_Trololo <-- would not compile, the callback is static.
                    })));
        #endregion
    }
```

Isn't this breaking encapsulation? how does it even compiles?

I'm asking this mainly because I make use of it in my WPF applications: it allows me to keep a variable private while still accessing it in callbacks.
But since it really doesn't feel right at all, I wouldn't want this to be "fixed" in WPF vNext, making my apps incompatible.

Best regards,

bab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback is defined in the same class that owns the private member, nothing wrong with that kind of access. It might seem odd that a private instance member is seemingly accessed "from the outside" but you are still in the same class.

Comment: Damn, you learn something everyday. In 2 years I've been programming, I never ever tried to access a private member like this. And here I was, thinking it was a Dependency Property mumbo jumbo magic. Silly me. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! If you want to see something *really* weird then have a look at [type covariance in arrays](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx) :D

Comment: I've read that article before. Several times until I understood actually xD But after having fought with sentinel objects, I keep an eye out for weirdness when it comes to my love-love-hate buddy, WPF. [Blog post](http://baboon.eu/)